# How to export a bq custom query to gcs using maps

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to export a bq custom query to gcs using maps, as I don't want to incur costs by using a temporary table in between.

If you have any other suggestions to go about this, please let me know as I am new to GCS!

P.s - I am not approved by my company to use dataflow.

I would also like to point out that is not a static query, I got to make it user friendly, where anyone can put in any complex query like joins, etc

```
def extractBqQueryToGcsViaMap(spark: SparkSession,configMap: mutable.Map[String, String], query: String): Unit = {

    logger_info("We have entered extract custom query to gcs function")
    val projectId = getConfiguration(configMap, "gcpProjectId")
    logger_info("The projectId is "+ projectId)
    val gcsLocation = getConfiguration(configMap, "gcsLocation")
    val pipelineId = getConfiguration(configMap,"pipelineId")
    val sanitizedPipelineId = pipelineId.replaceAll("-","_")
    val outputWriterFormat = "Parquet"
    val destinationUri = s"${gcsLocation}/${sanitizedPipelineId}-*.${outputWriterFormat}"
    val resultList: mutable.ListBuffer[(List[String], List[String])] = mutable.ListBuffer()

    val bigquery = getConnection(projectId, configMap)

    executeQueryAndStoreResult(configMap,query,resultList)
    try {
      // Convert the list of tuples to an RDD of Rows
      val rowsRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(resultList.map { case (_, columnValues) =>
        Row.fromSeq(columnValues)
      })

      // Define the schema
      val schema = StructType(resultList.head._1.map(col => StructField(col, StringType)))

      // Create DataFrame from RDD and schema
      val resultListDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRDD, schema)

      // Write DataFrame to Parquet format
      logger_info("Writing DataFrame to Parquet format at" +destinationUri)
      resultListDF.write.parquet(destinationUri)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error("Error occurred while writing DataFrame to Parquet format", e)
        throw e
    }

    }



    def executeQueryAndStoreResult(configMap: mutable.Map[String, String],query: String, resultList: mutable.ListBuffer[(List[String], List[String])]): Unit = {


    val projectId = getConfiguration(configMap, "gcpProjectId")
    logger_info("The projectId is "+ projectId)
    val bigquery = getConnection(projectId, configMap)
    val queryConfig: QueryJobConfiguration = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build
    val queryResult: TableResult = bigquery.query(queryConfig)

    // Retrieve column names
    val columnNames = queryResult.getSchema.getFields.asScala.map(_.getName).toList

    // Iterate over each row and store column names and values
    logger_info("Storing query result")
    queryResult.iterateAll().asScala.take(1000).foreach { row =>
      val values = columnNames.map(field => row.get(field).getStringValue).toList
      resultList += (columnNames -> values)
    }
    

  }
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> 24/02/19 06:10:39 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception:
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.